# Matlab NN-Toolbox: Howto convert a neural net to single precision

Tags: matlab, neural-network

Is it possible to convert a neural net into a single precision network. My attempt converting all weights into single precision using:

net.IW{1,1}(1,1)=single(net.IW{1,1}(1,1));

did not work. Any suggestions here how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay since nobody had a clue here is what I did so far:

```
function [ fi_net ] = conv2single( net, w , f )
%CONV2SINGLE Convert weights, biases of neural net to single precision
%   We are using fi objects,

% create fixed_point net, copy of the given net

fi_net = net;

% extract weights and bias from net
% convert to signed fixed point object of wordlength w, fraction length f

IW=fi(net.IW{1,1},1,w,f);
LW=fi(net.LW{2,1},1,w,f);
b_1=fi(net.b{1},1,w,f);
b_2=fi(net.b{2},1,w,f);

% write converted data back to fixedpoint net

fi_net.IW{1,1}=IW.data;
fi_net.LW{2,1}=LW.data;
fi_net.b{1}=b_1.data;
fi_net.b{2}=b_2.data;

end
```

With this function the approximation error of a fixed point implementation of the net can be roughly estimated.
If someone has a bette solutions to this, please let me know!

Cheers,
  Mick